# Using JavaScript, I cant get a dynamic header to display/not display based on the number of rows in the table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table where you start without any rows, but the user can dynamically add rows as needed (these will be rows of data that will get sent to the database). When the table does not have any rows, I don't want a header to be there, but once the user adds at least one or more rows to the table, I want the table's header to dynamically appear. I can't get this to work. I'm very new to this so any help is appreciated. Here is the code I currently have for this part:

```
<script>
//function to dynamically delete rows
function delete_row(rowno)
{
 $('#'+rowno).remove();
}
//function to dynamically add faculty row
function add_f_row()
{
 $rowno=$("#faculty_table tr").length;
 $rowno=$rowno+1;
 $("#faculty_table tr:last").after("<tr id='f_row"+$rowno+"'>"
 +"<td><input type='text' name='f_lname[]' placeholder='Last Name'></td>"
 +"<td><input type='text' name='f_fname[]' placeholder='First Name'></td>"
 +"<td><input type='text' name='f_org[]' placeholder='Organization'></td>"
 +"<td><input type='text' name='f_email[]' placeholder='Email'></td>"
 +"<td><input type='text' name='f_phone[]' placeholder='Phone'></td>"
 +"<td><select name='f_dept[]'><option value='' disabled selected>Select a Department</option>"
 +"<option value='Analytics and Data Science'>Analytics and Data Science</option>"
 +"<option value='Computer Science'>Computer Science</option>"
 +"<option value='Information Technology'>Information Technology</option>"
 +"<option value='Software Engineering and Game Development'>Software Engineering and Game Development</option>"
 +"</select></td><td><input type='text' name='f_title[]' placeholder='Title'></td>"
 +"<td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('f_row"+$rowno+"')></td></tr>");
}

  <h5>Faculty</h5>
        <table id="faculty_table" align=center>

            <!--This is the header mentioned in the problem-->
                       <tr id="f_row0">
                          <th>Last Name</th>
                          <th>First Name</th>
                          <th>Organization</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Phone</th>
                          <th>Department</th>
                          <th>Title</th>
                       </tr>
        </table>
        <!--script to add table header if there is one or more rows present-->
        <script>
           if ($("#faculty_table tr").length <= 1) {
             document.getElementById('f_row0').style.display = 'none';
           } else if ($("#faculty_table tr").length > 1) {
             document.getElementById('f_row0').style.display = '';
           }
        </script>
        <input type="button" onclick="add_f_row();" value="ADD FACULTY">
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just showing the dynamic header on the page then it can be solved by adding a flag to the function. This the way I included dynamic header to my demo app for adding dynamic row.

**script.js**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var flag = 1
        $(".add_f_row").click(() =>{
            if(flag){
                var header = "<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th></tr>";
                $("#mytable").append(header);
            }
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var tBody = "<tr><td>" + lname + "</td><td>" + fname + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(tBody);
            flag = 0;
        });

    });    
</script>
```

**dynamicHeader.html**

```
    <h5>Faculty</h5>
    <form>
        <label for="name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="button" class="add_f_row" value="Add Row">
    </form>
    <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Surely, there must be some other way to do that. All I did here was, just checked my `flag` value if it's `true` then on loading the document it will add the header however it won't add again as the `flag` value is now set to `false` thus it will just append the body of the other elements. 
You can modify your code like this.